# is it possible to add certificate extensions during signing process with microsoft ca?

Tags: certificate, csr, certificate-authority, certutil

I have been working on this task to sign a CSR (generated by third party) to be signed by a root CA, which is stored in a token. Sounds like a straightforward job, except that there is a requirement to add a set of extensions as well as subject alternative name to the certificate based on the specification. Since there is no way to alter the CSR to include these information, I assume this should be done during the signing process. However, I have spent lots of time reading the documentations of certutil and certreq to no avail. There seems to be no way to add information for an existing CSR.

Additional information: This has to be done using Microsoft CA due to the limitation of the security token, so OpenSSL is out of question.

I hope someone can help me in this tricky task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, check out he below link it is a good starting point

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2011/11/07/how-to-add-subject-alternative-name-to-your-certificate-requests-c.aspx